# What is the normal total time for Peer Review for a general paper submission (Not a Special Issue) in IETE Journal of Research Taylor Francis?

Tags: paper-submission

I have submitted a paper in IETE Journal of Research (http://www.tandfonline.com/loi/tijr20#.VrL0xvl97IW) on 22/09/15. Still the status is under review. Is it usual for this journal or I should make a polite query to the editor.

Answer (score 2):

Although I have never submitted to this journal, in my experience, this is not an unusually long period of time, especially [given all the delays that can stack up during peer review](https://dynamicecology.wordpress.com/2012/09/18/why-the-peer-review-process-is-so-slow/).

This has also been [studied recently](http://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0132557), with typical turnaround times of 14 weeks. When you consider the holiday break that many academics likely took in Dec/Jan, this is right in line with your delay.

That being said, after 4 months, I don't think many editors would mind a quick email to ask for an update. The last time I did this, the editor explained that they had had an unusually difficult time in finding reviewers. However, [do be polite and respectful of their time](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/10999/how-long-is-reasonable-to-wait-for-reply-from-an-editor) when you write the editor.